Using local or system wide fonts?
I working some months with LaTeX (to be more precise pdflatex for the translation) and I asked myself whether it is more useful to use local fonts, that are saved in a folder directly next to the tex file instead of using system wide fonts. The idea is that on every system the used font is available. As font type opentype fonts are used.
After reading some articles about LaTeX and fonts I got the impression that usually system wide fonts are used.
Is this true and it is recommended using local fonts? And if not: Are there specific reasons?

If you are talking about opentype fonts then the fonts take up by far the largest part of the entire distribution. A lot more than all the tex code.  If you copy the fonts for every document that is a lot of disk space if you are using large unicode fonts

note that classic tex (latex or pdflatex) can not use system fonts (although you could still in theory use fonts in the document directory rather than fonts that come with the tex system)

welcome! there's really no general answer to this, imho, beyond 'it depends'. if you're sending the .tex to somebody and it requires a font which isn't generally available (maybe you need special symbols or something) and the licence permits it, it may make sense to keep that particular font in your working directory (or at least a note or link reminding you). but if you keep all fonts required for all documents with the documents, you'll have font files everywhere, possibly many outdated. if you always send pdf, just make sure fonts are embedded, which you should anyway.

@DavidCarlisle Yes I am talking about opentype fonts.

@goto-vulture you could even now clarify that that is what you mean (as "latex" can not read opentype at all, so you mean lualatex or xelatex) but as I say do you really want 1.1MiB of (for example)  NewCMMath-Regular.otf copied to every document folder?

@DavidCarlisle Yes, you are right. I added the information in the question.

You mention pdflatex in your question. Pdflatex is based on pdftex engine and it is unable to read opentype fonts directly because it is an ancient TeX engine. But you mention opentype fonts in your question. There is a contradiction here. What is true? opentype fonts or pdflatex? Both cannot be true together.

There are essentially three ways of installing fonts that can be used by luatex or xetex

In a directory local to the document, loaded by a relative path
In your texlive or miktex installation font tree
As a system font (\windows\fonts or /usr/share/fonts or wherever your system puts fonts.

The first is the simplest, and useful for testing, or if the document uses a local non standard font and you want to zip up the document source along with its fonts, to share with other people. However OpenType fonts can be large (often over a Megabyte  7.5M for CJK fonts such as FandolKai-Regular.otf)
so if you use the font in more than one document you almost always want to use one of the other shared locations so you only need one copy.
The second way makes the font available to tex related programs without installing it system wide for your system desktop applications. This matches how you would install latex packages or other tex files such as bibliography styles.
The main disadvantage is that the document has "hidden dependencies" on the font installation and would not work on a site which had not installed the font. That is the same as relying on a locally installed document class etc.
The third way is often the easiest to do, eg on Windows you can just drag and drop the font into the font directory, but you may not wish (or may not have permission) to make system wide changes.
